# Test HTTP headers with Protractor: (X-)Content-Security-Policy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, webdriver, protractor

Is there a way that I can test the HTTP headers sent along with the main HTML page with Protractor? Specifically I would like to test to ensure the security-related (`X-`)`Content-Security-Policy` header is present:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; font-src 'self';
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to test for its effects rather than just its presence, as this would be better at ensuring the page behaves as I want it to behave.

Comment: Add a "webdriver" tag, as I think this functionality for controlling the browser would likely come from there.  (I'd add the tag myself, but didn't know which tag you'd want dropped.)

Comment: @P.T. Done, thanks! (Added Selenium for good measure... If they're not quite the best tags, feel free to edit them)

Answer (score 1):

The below seems to (at least partialy) test (in Chrome) the presence of `script-src 'self'`, in that it tests if injected inline scripts can be run. So actually tests if the value is does not contain `unsafe-inline` or `*`:

```
it('should not run injected scripts', function() {
  var script = 'window.inlineTagEvaluated = false;';
  script += 'var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];';
  script += 'var script = document.createElement("script");';
  script += 'script.text = "window.inlineTagEvaluated = true;";';
  script += 'document.head.appendChild(script);'
  script += 'callback(window.inlineTagEvaluated);';

  expect(browser.executeAsyncScript(script)).toBe(false);
});
```

Testing that the CSP means we can't run `unsafe-eval` code is a bit tricky. Since inline script is forbidden, I can't inject a usage of `eval` into the page at runtime. The way I've done it is to put a file on the server `/test-eval.js` that contains the following (thanks to the AngularJS source for a way of doing this)

```
try {
  new Function('');
}
catch(e) {
  window.caught = true;
}
```

and then add it to the DOM at runtime of the test:

```
it('should not run eval-ed scripts', function() {
  var script = 'window.caught = false;'
  script += 'var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];';
  script += 'var script = document.createElement("script");';
  script += 'script.src = "/eval-test.js";';
  script += 'script.onload = function() {callback(window.caught);};';
  script += 'script.onerror = function() {callback(window.caught);};';
  script += 'document.head.appendChild(script);'

  expect(browser.executeAsyncScript(script)).toBe(true);
});
```

I have to admit, I'm not a fan of having to have something on the server I'm testing that is only for the test.

Testing the we can't run scripts from other domains is also a bit tricky. For this, I setup a HTTP server for the lifetime of a single test, serving up a simple Javascript file. (It is served from a different port from the rest of the site, and so is treated as a different domain for the purposes of CSP).

```
it('should not run scripts from another domain', function() {

  function setupServer() {
    var defer = protractor.promise.defer();

    require('http').createServer(function (request, response) {
       response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
       response.end('window.externalScriptEvaluated = true;');
    }).listen(8081, function() {
      defer.fulfill();
    });
    return defer.promise;
  }
  protractor.promise.controlFlow().execute(setupServer);

  var script = 'window.externalScriptEvaluated = false;';
  script += 'var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];';
  script += 'var script = document.createElement("script");';
  script += 'script.src = "http://localhost:8081/";';
  script += 'script.onload = function() {callback(window.externalScriptEvaluated);};';
  script += 'script.onerror = function() {callback(window.externalScriptEvaluated);};';
  script += 'document.head.appendChild(script);'
  expect(browser.executeAsyncScript(script)).toBe(false);
});
```

The following partially tests the presence of `style-src 'self'`, in that it tests if inline styles can be applied (so actually tests if the value is does not contain `unsafe-inline` or `*`)

```
it('should not use injected styles', function() {
  var script = 'document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0, 1, 1)";';
  script += 'var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];';
  script += 'var style = document.createElement("style");';
  script += 'style.type = "text/css";';
  script += 'style.appendChild(document.createTextNode("body {background-color: rgb(1, 0, 0) !important}"));';
  script += 'document.head.appendChild(style);'
  script += 'callback(window.getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue("background-color"));';

  expect(browser.executeAsyncScript(script)).toBe("rgb(0, 1, 1)");
});
```